# Json parsing have some difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing some difficulty in parsing the data in my MVC application.

This is my code. I am getting values in the InitialRowData.

```
 var initdata = jQuery.parseJSON(InitialRowData);
```

But throwing exception during the run, the initdata is null.

This is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Floor/LoadFloor',
    data:ko.mapping.toJSON( {floorId:'@Model.FloorID'}),
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    error: function (error) {
        alert("error");
        alert(error.responseText);
    }
}).done(function (data) {

    InitialRowData = data;
});
```

Any help please?

Comment: Where are you parsing? I am sure your response data is already in JSON format. Thus you don't need to use `jQuery.parseJSON` just try with data directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

```
            $.ajax({
                    url: "URL",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: "data",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },

                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert('Failed');
                        alert(x.responseText);
                        alert(x.status);
                    }
                });
```

Here You can parse the `response` with json result

In Methos use like

```
return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To Return `Json` Result

Comment: looks like `response` is already an object parsed from json string because we set `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: it will give you json out put if you will return json with you back end method

Comment: what do you mean? the `response` can be an object and can also be a string? it depends on something? so you should add that note in your answer.

Comment: hi what is ty in JSON.stringify(ty) please, i didnt understand that

Comment: you can use direct data instead of that, by the way it will convert data to json string

Comment: shall i put like this JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: if you have string and you want to convert into json then only else try to give only your data to back end